# Most precise way of updating the UI based on markers from an AudioTrack?

Tags: android, synchronization, surface, audiotrack

I am needing precise syncing between an AudioTrack and the screen. The screen content is standard views created with XML. The screen updates are very simple, consisting (currently) of switching single small images through a ViewFlipper UI component. The changes are only occuring once every two seconds to 3 times a second, and I'm currently using `onMarkerReached()` of the AudioTrack and updating the UI on the main thread that way.

This is working pretty good, except on low end devices there appears to be some inconsitency between the audio and when the screen updates, which is not acceptable. What classes should I be looking at in order to update the screen more precisely? I am understanding that a Surface can update the screen off the main thread, is this going to be the way to go?

I would like to continue to use the Java AudioTrack implementation, if possible.

Comment: I would first check, what is actually out of sync -- the marker events arriving later, or the graphical updates being slow. For example by just logging in marker events and looking at log records timestamps. Also, how do you initialize AudioTrack? E.g. if you use compressed audio, the decompression may happen in hardware, and it may be providing late or inaccurate updates.

Comment: I checked System.nanoTime() coming out of onMarkerReacher(). It is always accurate to a couple of milliseconds, usually down to the millisecond. The problem is I call ViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild() and the screen sometimes is very late in updating. I see other apps that do the same thing and I don't see this problem. Should I be looking at SurfaceView class?

Comment: SurfaceView is used when you need to render something by yourself. It's indeed one of the fastest ways to draw in Android. The other way is TextureView, but it's mostly for video and 3D graphics.